# java.io.FileNotFoundException when trying to access photo while doing more photos quickly

Tags: android, image, file, photo, android-storage

I have an application that listens to new photos on a device, resizes them and uploads to cloud.

When I'm doing photos with **small pause** between them (for example 1 second) everything is ok, but when I'm doing photos **quickly without any pause** I've got exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20180116_150824_1.jpg (No such file or directory)
```

in my **compressAndResize** function.

In that function I'm doing stuff like this:

```
 private static File compressAndResizeImage(File sourceFile, File destination) throws IOException {

    File compressedAssetFile = new File(destination, sourceFile.getName());

    if (!compressedAssetFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
        //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
        compressedAssetFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
    //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
    compressedAssetFile.getParentFile().createNewFile();

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

    int width;
    int height;

    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(compressedAssetFile);

        Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());

        int sourceWidth = source.getWidth();
        int sourceHeight = source.getHeight();
...
```

Exception is thrown in **BitmapFactory.decodeFile** method.

I have no idea why such behavior happens when I'm doing photos fast.

**Could some one explain my why does it happen?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `compressedAssetFile.getParentFile().createNewFile();`. Remove that line. You are trying to create a file with the same name as the directory you just created.

Comment: Thanks for reply and tip! But the issue happens with **sourceFile** object.

Comment: You posted more code to create directories and files then just reading files. Please do a test in which you just call in a loop `Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());`. Nothing more.

Comment: @greenapps I already created such test, I'm added rx java wrapper for this method and doing retry when can't access source file and it works. but I want to know why exactly does this happen?